# CSV grep but keep the header

Tags: linux, csv, awk, grep

I have a CSV file that look like this:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,4,4
1,2,6
3,6,9
```

Is there an easy way to grep all the rows in which the B column is 2, and keep the header? For example, I want the output be like

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
1,2,6
```

I am working under linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 || $2==2' file
```

NR==1 -> if first line, 
$2==2 -> if second column is equal to 2. Lines are printed if either of the above is true.

To choose the column using the header column name:

```
awk -F, -v col="B" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==col)break;print;next}$i==2'  file
```

Replace B with the appropriate name of the column which you want to check against.

Comment: Thanks Guru, but is there a way to replace $2 with the header column name? my CSV has a lot of columns so it's hard to count....

Comment: @CodeNoob: Updated the solution above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use addresses in `sed`:

```
sed -n '1p;/^[^,]*,2/p'
```

It means:

```
1p        Print the first line.
/         Start a match.
    ^     Match the beginnning of a line.
    [^,]  Match anything but a comma
    *     zero or more times.
    ,     Match a comma.
    2     Match a 2.
/p        End of match, if it matches, print.
```

If the header can contain the value you are looking for, you should be more careful:

```
sed -n '1p;1!{/^[^,]*,2/p}'
```

`1!{ ... }` just means "Do the following for lines other then the first one".

For column number `n>2`, you can add a quantifier:

```
sed -n '1p;1!{/^\([^,]*,\)\{M\}2/p}'
```

where `M=n-1`. The quantifier just means repetition, so the *non-comma-0-or-more-times-comma* thing is repeated M times.

For true CSV files where a value can contain a comma, switch to Perl and [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV).

Comment: thanks choroba, but can you translate these for me? I just see a hell lot of strange characters but have no idea what they mean

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) h[$i] = i; print; next } $h["B"] == 2' file
A,B,C
1,2,3
1,2,6
```

By the way, sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else, just use awk - the code will be clearer and MUCH easier to enhance in future if necessary.